# How to connect Visualization Toolkit (VTK) libraries to OS X project in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew, vtk, itk

I am trying to write a simple application trying to get my feet wet with VTK. Here is where I am so far. After searching for a while and attempting to download and build with CMAKE unsuccessfully, I found this blog from KitWare: https://blog.kitware.com/kitware-packages-on-os-x-with-homebrew/

So, I went off, installed homebrew, I believe "installed" VTK and Insight ToolKit. This was followed by self high-fives and all around self-congratulations. But.. I'm still not where I need to be.

I can't seem to sort out where to go from here. I believe I'm at the critical "now link the libraries with your project" state. I can find the installs under "/usr/local/cellar/Vtk/7.0.0_5/include/" and "/usr/local/cellar/Vtk/7.0.0_5/lib/" folders. The "include" folder has a bunch of ".h" files. The "lib" folder has a bunch of ".dylib" files. In a Xcode (V8.1) CoCoa Project, I've linked iokit, cocoa, and openGL frameworks and it builds. However, when I try to include something like "vtkActor.h", it fails to find it unless I specifically link that file.

Updated! Screen shot of search paths: 
[image]

So, my questions are thus:

1. Am I actually done installing? I thought I was to end up with some ".a" files. Whats up with that?
2. If I am done, and I'm linked to all those .dylib files, why isn't it working? Should I link to all the ".h" files?
3. I've tried linking the folder "usr/local/cellar/vtk" folder, but it fails. Should I be doing that, but making it "recursive" I believe is the word.
4. Long run for a short slide... Anyone have any good tutorials/examples of a running Xcode OS X project so that I can get an idea how these libraries actually interact once I can even get them linked?

Thanks so much for your wisdom in advance. If anyone would have the kindness for mentorship off-stack until I can get up and running, I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: I'm curious to see how your project is set up. For the following build settings (HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS;LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS;FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS), what are the paths that you use? Are you setting these options directly in the project settings or are you using a xcconfig file?

Comment: Alright alright alright! That might be the trick. At least to get up and running. What I did was have it look in "/user/local/cellar/vtk/7.0.0_5/include/".. The other option I did was to make them recursive. Anyone think that was the right idea? It now builds and can find the proper h files.